# type guards and extending a union type?

Tags: typescript, types, assert, extends

I have an array of objects where each item either extends `{x: method}` or `{y: method}` and I want to try and separate them. I've written the following

```
export const refresh = <
  N extends HasRefresh | HasRefreshWithFoo,
  RefreshWithFoo extends HasRefreshWithFoo,
  RefreshNormal extends HasRefresh
>(
  ns: N[],
  foos: Foo[]
) => {
  const refreshWithFoo: RefreshWithFoo = ns.filter((n): n is RefreshWithFoo  =>
    n.x !== undefined
  ) 
}
```

But I'm getting the error

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'RefreshNormal' is not assignable to type 'N'.
```

Given an array of objects containing items extending HasRefreshWithFoo or extending HasRefresh, how can I separate the array with the union so that I have one array with only RefreshNormal and one with only RefreshWithFoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow the compiler error by making another abstraction of generic types.
The second abstraction would be responsible of filtering an array by a given type.

```
const filterByType = <T>(arr: any[], key: keyof T): T[] =>
    arr.filter(e => (<T>e)[key]) as T[];
```

Following the [Typescript guide of how to type guard an instance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), we are forced to specify what key to check if the casting was efectively done (a unique key in the type we are filtering by).

So, we can now filter in our function by `RefreshWithFoo`

```
export const refresh = <
  N extends HasRefresh | HasRefreshWithFoo,
  RefreshWithFoo extends HasRefreshWithFoo,
  RefreshNormal extends HasRefresh
>(
    ns: N[], 
    foos: Foo[]
) => {
    const refreshWithFoo: RefreshWithFoo[] = filterByType<RefreshWithFoo>(ns, `x`);
}
```

Without any compiler complain.
Well I am using a default *tsconfig*, I assume this won't complain with any other compiler configuration. If so, let me know.

**Edit**
In some case like type intersection you will need more than one key to check for. You could simply extend the method by expecting a params array of keys and check for all of them, like so

```
const filterByType = <T>(arr: any[], ...keys: (keyof T)[]): T[] =>
    arr.filter(e => keys.every(k => (<T>e)[k])) as T[];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This kinda works but I am having trouble if type is an intersection or has multiple keys. Any way to extend it so it implements all keys of type T?

Comment: You don't have to check for all the keys but for a unique key which is only present in the type you are checking for.  In the case of type intersections, you cannot filter for an specific type. Having two types, A and B, an instance of (A&B) is not A OR B anymore, so filtering by A OR B makes no sense.

Comment: I get that but if we have <{a: string} & {b: string}>filterByType(arr, 'a') we didn't actually verify that it has b as well. In some cases I need to filter those who are intersection multiple types because I can have an array containing [val1: (A & B & C), val2 : (B & C), val3: (C & A)] and I want to extract those that have A & B, filtering for one of the keys won't work then. I might create a new question for this.

Comment: Well, propabibly you should. However, I am gonna update the answer to fit that case.